# "emacsclientw -c " runs very slow as an outlook macro, while super fast if runs in Window Powershell

Tags: vba, emacs, outlook, emacsclient

Here is a simple command to launch an emacsclient frame in Windows 10,  which I've added to outlook as a macro assigned to a new button.

```
Shell ("c:/Users/user_name/emacs-25.3-x86_64/bin/emacsclientw.exe -c ")
```

But every time it is launched through that button, the outlook message window becomes non-responsive for 15+ seconds.

If I change that macro to:

```
Shell ("c:/Users/user_name/emacs-25.3-x86_64/bin/runemacs.exe")
```

i,e, to launch emacs instead of emacsclient, it can finish instantaneously without any impact to outlook window.

If I launch emacsclient directly in a Windows Powershell with this command:

```
c:/Users/user_name/emacs-25.3-x86_64/bin/emacsclientw.exe -c
```

a new frame can also pop up instantaneously without any noticeable impact to anything.

so launch "emacsclientw -c" directly is fast, so is launch emacs through an outlook macro. but launch "emacsclientw -c " through an outlook macro is very slow.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is the case?

(BTW, "runemacs.exe --daemon" is part of my Windows startup script.)